# How can I insert rows into my DB daily using Cron Jobs?

Tags: php, mysql, time, pdo, cron

I have this Cron Job that I want to run once a day. It checks to see if it's a new day, and if it is, it inserts a new row into my database table. I use this to keep track of the daily sales for each item on my online store.

- I also need it to grab the `day` from the last row for that product_id, increment it by 1 and then include it in my `INSERT` query. This is so that I can easily keep track of the current day for each product.
- The `MAX(time_stamp)` is also illegal code, however I don't know what to replace it with. I use it to select the latest day for each item, so that the Cron Job doesn't select every single row.

I've never used Cron Jobs before, meaning that I'm a noob so please be easy on me :)

Thanks for the help! :)

Here's my code:

PHP:

```
// Checks if past a day
$days = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM `daily_sales` WHERE MAX(time_stamp)<=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY;");
$numrows = count($days);

// If there is a new day
if ($numrows > 0) {
    foreach ($days as $i => $day) {
        // Adds a fresh day with 0 sales
        $sales = 0;
        $product_id = $day->product_id;
        $day = // Get the day from the last row, and add 1
        $time_stamp = time();
        DB::query('INSERT INTO `daily_sales` (`product_id`, `sales`, `day`, `time_stamp`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);', array($product_id, $sales, $day, $time_stamp));
    }
}
```

`daily_sales`: (the DB table)

```
id | product_id | day | time_stamp | sales
```

Comment: Is your question how to setup a cron job? I would suggest you take a look at the man page for that? 'cause that is what man pages are there for? `man cron`, `man crontab`, ...

Comment: No, I want to make the code for this Cron Job

Comment: Sorry, then the question is even more unclear. You posted your code. So what do you expect from us?

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused, and I tried posting a clear question but I was having trouble what to ask because I have no idea what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

you have to open cron job, add new job and define

how to open cron tab

```
crontab -e
```

add following to your cron tab

```
0 0 * * * php /full/path/to/script.php
```

OR

you can use mysql triggers http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx that will allow you to make "audit" table which will contain daly sales. So you can insert/update audit table by using "after insert".

hope this will help

Comment: "0 0 * * *" means that the script would be executed every day 0 hour 0 minute

Comment: I have a similar task and I use mysql triggers, it allows to make "audit" table that contains daly information (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx).

Comment: Ok thanks. If I use cPanel to trigger the Cron Jobs, does that mean I still set the 'MAX(time_stamp)<=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY' in my PHP document? I'm really confused

Comment: your code is confusing. I would suggest you to have two different tables. 1) sales (id (pk), product_id, timestamp). This table contains all information about sales. 2) daily_sales (date, product_id, number_sales) and primary key would be date, product_id. In the end you need to make mysql trigger that will update/insert daily_sales if there is new record in sales table. IN this case you will not need any cron job!